# DOMDocument disable character escaping

Tags: php, xml, json

I am trying to disable DOMDocument character escaping.

So when have node from JSON like this one:
`"something": "<>shouldnotescape"`

I want it to produce the exact same output in xml:
`<something value="<>shouldnotescape"/>`
Instead I get: `<something value="&lt;&gt;shouldnotescape"/>`

I have already tried turning off substituteElements and resolveExternals, also tried `$this->document->saveXML($this->document->documentElement);` but nothing worked for me.

I am not loading XML, instead, I am traversing the JSON tree and creating DOMElements. The values on each element are non-escaped before saving, so I believe, this should be somehow possible via DOMDocument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be invalid XML. So it is not possible.

Example:

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml('<something value="<>shouldnotescape"/>');
```

Output:

```
Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Unescaped '<' not allowed in attributes values in Entity, line: 1 in /tmp/... on line 3    
Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): attributes construct error in Entity, line: 1 in /tmp/... on line 3
```

You need to be aware that this is only the serialization. If you fetch the value of the attribute the entities will be decoded:

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml('<something value="&lt;&gt;shouldnotescape"/>');
var_dump($dom->documentElement->getAttribute('value'));
```

Output:

```
string(17) "<>shouldnotescape"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, what I am doing now is simply calling htmlspecialchars_decode over the whole xml to take it back. (It's so silly specification).
Before you ask why, it's school project, that's why.