# PHP DOMElement class: Do not escape special characters

Tags: php

What is the correct way to use the DOMElement class to create a text node so that it does not escape characters such as `&`, `<`?

This is particularly a problem when generating `<script>` tags that contain JavaScript. Operators such as `<` and `&&` are escaped, breaking the JavaScript code.

Comment: can you show an example of the code you are using?

Comment: I can't excerpt a chunk of code cleanly without including a lot of irrelevant context. Suffice it to say I'm calling `createTextNode()` on a DOMDocument item then appending the resulting node to its parent element.

Comment: @JayBienvenu Is the result/output XML code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DOMDocument disable character escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29104957/domdocument-disable-character-escaping)

Comment: The result is HTML code. Specifically a <script> element. The question you linked doesn't answer my question. It provides a non-answer, but not an actual answer. A valid answer to my question is one that produces correct <script> elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`DOMDocument::createCDATASection()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createcdatasection.php) to create a text block where the characters are not escaped when using the `saveHtml()` method.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$root = $dom->createElement('html');
$root = $dom->appendChild($root);

$text = $dom->createCDATASection("some < text & with special characters");
$text = $root->appendChild($text);

var_dump($dom->saveHtml());

var_dump($dom->saveXml());
```

This will create the following output:

```
string(51) "<html>some < text & with special characters</html>
"
string(85) "<?xml version="1.0"?>
<html><![CDATA[some < text & with special characters]]></html>
"
```

When you want to use `saveXml()` and want to use the special characters as well (for javascript) you might want to check the [comment on DOMDocument::createCDataSection()](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createcdatasection.php#82021):

> A common issue seems to be adding javascript to CDATA and the browser throwing a javascript error. To ensure the javascript works use the following code when adding CDATA:
>
> ```
> <?php
> /**
> * Append Caracter Data to a node and check for a javascript node
> * 
> * @param DOMElement $appendToNode
> * @param string $text
> */
> function appendCdata($appendToNode, $text) 
> {
>     if (strtolower($appendToNode->nodeName) == 'script') {  // Javascript hack
>         $cm = $appendToNode->ownerDocument->createTextNode("\n//");
>         $ct = $appendToNode->ownerDocument->createCDATASection("\n" . $text . "\n//");
>         $appendToNode->appendChild($cm);
>         $appendToNode->appendChild($ct);
>     } else {  // Normal CDATA node
>         $ct = $appendToNode->ownerDocument->createCDATASection($text);
>         $appendToNode->appendChild($ct);
>     }
> }
> ?>
> ```
>
> The result should be:
>
> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
> //<![CDATA[
> function someJsText() {
>    document.write('Some js with <a href="#">HTML</a> content');
> }
> //]]></script>
> ```

This will create a valid CDATA section where the CDATA syntax is commented out for the javascript parser.